# Problem in cluster sampling: 'mixed with negative subscripts'

Tags: cluster-analysis, simulation, data-generation

I was trying to do a cluster sampling but came across this error:
`Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`
What is the cause and how to get around? Thank you for your help!

Here is the code:

```
#simulate some data
y <- rnorm(20)
x <- rnorm(20)
z <- rep(1:5, 4)
w <- rep(1:4, each=5)
dd <- data.frame(id=z, cluster=w, x=x, y=y)

clusters <- split(dd, dd$cluster) #split into clusters
k <- length(clusters) #length of clusters
# This function generates a cluster sample
clsamp <- function() dd[unlist(clusters[sample.int(k, k, replace = TRUE)], use.names = TRUE), ]
clsamp()
```

I got this error: `Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: change the split line to `clusters <- split(seq_len(nrow(dd)), dd$cluster)`